# Get Button in UITableViewCell to use all available space

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableViewCell with a button in it. The cell has nothing else but a button.

I would like the button take up all of the cell, something like this:

[image]

but I can't quite get it with constraints.

Perhaps, I just shouldn't use buttons to get the desired effect.

Comment: Why are you using buttons in that case? There is an delegate method to handle touches in cells (didSelectRowAtIndexPath)

Comment: Yes, use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` use uilabel instead a uibutton and the se label with `userInteractionEnable` in false

Comment: @jose920405 why set label's `userInteractionEnable` to false? It's unnecessary.

Comment: That worked, now I just need to get the rounded corners. This seemed to make top part of the first cell rounded: tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10

Answer (score 0):

As the other commenters have mentioned, you could easily use didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method to handle the tap on the cell.  As for the look of the cell, you can put a UIView in the table view cell that takes up the size of the cell.  Then, you can round the corners of that view.  If needed, you could make the background of the table view cell clear so all you see are the rounded views.  The words can just be labels placed in the cell/view as well.